# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component in WP8 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

Im totally lost and i tried everything that is on StackOverflow. I have Windows Phone app, that use Windows Live SDK and use login throught this SDK (LiveConnect.Login) that show browser with login inputs. When you click into input and leave it, app crash on the error shows in below. Before that i update Visual Studio 2012 Express for WP to VS 2013 Update 3 for Windows. I don't known what to do now. I tried to all clean, rebuild, restart everithing, udpate into version that is on store and its working and get same error in this version. I don't get it and this issue solving 3 days. It's very frustrating.

There is a error call stack

```
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, String s)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase doh, DependencyProperty property, Object obj)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Object newValue)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.SetShrinkAmount(Double bottomObscuredBySIP)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.OnGotSipFocusFromYamanotePage(Double bottomObscuredBySIP)
   at System.Windows.Controls.SipHelper.FlickIn(FrameworkElement element, Double bottomMargin)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.SipChange()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.set_VisibleRegionInPhysicalPixels(RECT value)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.UpdateCurrentVisualState()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.HandleVisibleRegionChange()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.OnVisibleRegionChange()
   at Microsoft.Phone.TaskModel.Interop.Task.FireOnVisibleRegionChange()
```

Thans for help.

Comment: are using some 3rd party toolkits? like Telerik?

Comment: I use only Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll - Version=8.0.1.0, Newtonsoft.Json.dll and Sparrow.Chart.WP8.45.dll but i use it before and everything was good.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your designer right? Its happens when you run the app?

Comment: Here's [another victim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21627272/windows-phone-webbrowser-keyboard-exception).  Made the same mistake and provided no repro code.

Comment: Its not about repro code, because is external library and suprislly on Nokia this same package work on HTC 8X not work. And it's only webBrowser component with Live login screen in app. Thats all

Comment: @KasunKodagoda I dont think so, i just update VS from 2012 to 2013 ...

Comment: Still can not solve problem, i try to uninstal and install studio and SDK. Nothing .....

Comment: @KasunKodagoda I found that its only problem in my app, if i create new app with web browser control it's ok. I dont get it :(

Comment: It seems a joke, but had the same problem and [this topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0fa34a87-a42c-495f-ad35-8fec21ceecdd/error-hresult-efail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component-in-wp8-app?forum=wpdevelop) gave me a light.
In the Loaded event, I was loading a list of available languages using SpeechRecognizer.

After removing the call, the problem completely stopped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by setting the property "ScrollBarsEnabled" to false before setting the web browser text property and set it back to true after setting the text.

```
WebBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
WebBrowser1.DocumentText = "Your HTML String";
WebBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
```